# Scraping Multiple Websites with Single Spider using Scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to scrape data from [this website](http://jobs.placementindia.com/lucknow). Following is the code for spider .

```
class StackItem(scrapy.Item):
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    if key not in self.fields:
        self.fields[key] = scrapy.Field()
    self._values[key] = value

class betaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "betaSpider"


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(betaSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.start_urls = [kwargs.get('start_url')]

    rules = (Rule (LinkExtractor(unique=True, allow=('.*\?id1=.*',),restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="prevNext next"]',)), callback="parse_items", follow= True),)

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        posts = hxs.select("//article[@class='classified']")
        items = []

        for post in posts:
            item = StackItem()
            item["job_role"] = post.select("div[@class='uu mb2px']/a/strong/text()").extract()
            item["company"] = post.select("p[1]/text()").extract()
            item["location"] = post.select("p[@class='mb5px b red']/text()").extract()
            item["desc"] = post.select("details[@class='aj mb10px']/text()").extract()
            item["read_more"] = post.select("div[@class='uu mb2px']/a/@href").extract()
            items.append(item)
            for item in items:
                yield item
```

This is the code for item pipelines:

```
class myExporter(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.myCSV = csv.writer(open('out.csv', 'wb'))
    self.myCSV.writerow(['Job Role', 'Company','Location','Description','Read More'])

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.myCSV.writerow([item['job_role'], item['company'], item['location'], item['desc'], item['read_more']])

    return item
```

This is working fine. Now, i have to scrape following websites (for example) using same spider.

1. http://www.freejobalert.com/government-jobs/
2. https://www.sarkariexaam.com/

I have to scrape all the tags of the above mentioned websites, store it to a CSV file using item pipelines.

Actually, the list of websites to be scrapped is endless. In this project, user will enter the url and scrapped results will be returned back to that user. So, i want a generic spider which can scrape any website.

For a single website, it is working fine. But, how can it be accomplished for multiple site having different structure ?
Is Scrapy enough to solve it?

Comment: I suggest you use different spiders if structure of websites are different. I've always done it like that and found my code easy to maintain at a later point.

Comment: Actually, the list of websites to be scrapped is endless. In this project, user will enter the url and scrapped results will be returned back to that user. So, i want a generic spider which can scrape any website

Comment: Is it something like import.io? If so, its a bit of work. I believe you're planning something which looks for more specific information than what is done by import.io.

Comment: Exactly, i want to mimic the behavior of import.io

Comment: You're looking at an absolutely massive amount of work if you plan on writing a single generic spider capable of crawling any page a user points at it.  Your code will effectively have to do what you do: open up a page you've never seen before, detect what fields of relevance are on the page, determine how/where the page associates data, contextually extract it, and then handle that data.

Comment: @Rejected Please provide some code examples doing a part of these functionalities

Comment: None of that is small drop-in code.  You want to mimic the functionality of an app with a 20+ person development team. My point was to say that's not a realistic approach for a one-person project, and I suggest that you look into other methods.

Comment: You'd need to use Machine Learning techniques to be able to extract the data you want from unknown pages. Check Scrapely (http://github.com/scrapy/scrapely), it's a library for automatic data extraction from the web. This talk (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GzNDcmWHuuE) gives a great overview of the challenges of projects like this.

Comment: If someone looking at this in 2020: HtmlXPathSelector is not used anymore in scrapy, some examples here: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html

Answer (score 0):

Different spider will be better You can use the API to run Scrapy from a script, instead of the typical way of running Scrapy crawl Remember that Scrapy is built on top of the Twisted asynchronous networking library, so you need to run it inside the Twisted reactor.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create a generic spider to scrape data from differet websites.That can be done by adding website one by one to the spider and generalizing the code.

It will be very vast code if the websites are entirely different. From your requirments the we can generalize the code and make a spider that give above details if any website is given.